# Как сохранить Graphics в картинку?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Я пишу проект основанный на WinFroms.
Создал `Panel` элемент. Переопределил метод отрисовки `Canvas_Paint`.
Хочу всё, что я успел отрисовать на `e.Graphis` сохранить в картинку (png). Как я могу это сделать?

На форуме уже есть ответы, однако они мне не подходят. Там сначала создают `Bitmap`, а из него создают `Graphics`. А у меня `Graphics` приходит в качестве аргумента.

```
private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(_backgroundColor);
    NormalizeView(e.Graphics);
            
    DrawAxes(Canvas.CreateGraphics());
    DrawGraph(e.Graphics);
}
```

Comment: `panel.DrawToBitmap` не пойдёт?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov разве не надо переопределять OnPrint, чтобы для переопределенного OnPaint заработало?

Comment: @aepot - я не помню. Надо тестить.

Comment: @aepot - проверил: работает без OnPrint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PanelImage : Panel
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
    public Graphics BitmapGraphics => Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap);
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bitmap, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
    public PanelImage()
    {
        Bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        Bitmap = new Bitmap(Bitmap, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Что вам нужно сделать:

1. Рисуете всё, что вам нужно на Bitmap через BitmapGraphics
2. Применяете обновляете PanelImage, OnPaint сам всё сделает за вас
3. Сохранить можете через PanelImage.Bitmap.Save() в нужный вам файл
   Например: `Bitmap.Save("1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`

PS Пока рисуете/обновляете график - не обновляйте сам PanelImage, это медленно, просто считайте области обновления прямоугольниками, и складывайте их через: Rectangle.Union, а потом просто вызываете обновления области `PanelImage.Invalidate(rectangle)`

Comment: PictureBox? )))

Comment: @aepot Я вот не помню, является ли PictureBox контейнером. Да и просто я уже забыл про него, в моём понимании PictureBox - почти та же панель, только с возможностью заранее загрузить картинку при формошлёпстве (хотя и в Bitmap наверное студия тоже позволит), а это в подавляющем большинстве случаев - лишнее, имхо. Как-то потребовалось рисовать realtime график с десятками тысяч точек и 60+ fps, о PictureBox в таком случае не было и речи. Только SetDIBitsToDevice - только хардкор.

Comment: Странно, на моем ноутбуке я со всякими графическими штукам пользуюсь, PB выдает на FullHD на чистом без постороннего кода бенчмарке более 200 FPS. То есть если ресурсов хватит, можно хоть скринкаст сделать через него. В общем, это точно не узкое место в производительности, во всяком случае в .NET 5. Но чем ближе к низкоуровневому рендеру - тем быстрее, конечно.

Comment: @aepot PB со статическим изображением? А если очень много вызовов отрисовки на сам PB? Может в .NET5 вызовы переделали. Но в FW4.6 главная проблема с отрисовкой - это GDI+ вызовы, которых очень много, и которые медленные.